# How to check whether a field value exists in existing documents in mongodb through react js?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

I have been trying to enter the email Id and save it in a document in mongo db collection named emails through react js. I have been successfully able to save the new document but I want to validate it if the email Id exists in any document,I want to throw a message to the user to enter a new email ID. I have tried the code for it as well but it throws an error "blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

code I tried is :

```
Model - Emails.js

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var EmailSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: String,

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Emails', EmailSchema);
```

Api- Email.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Email = require('../models/Emails.js');
var User = require('../models/User.js');
var async = require('async');
var helper = require('./helper.js');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var multer = require('multer');
var config = require('../config.js');

/* SAVE email */

router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {


     // below code is the working code

     console.log('req body:',+req.body);

     Email.create(req.body, function(err, post) {       
    if (err) {
        console.log('error:',+err);
        return res.json({success: false, msg: 'Email Id already exists.'});
    }

    res.json(post);
    return res.json({success: true, msg: 'Successful registered new Email Id.'});
  });  // this code works without validation     


   Email.findOne({ email: req.body }, function(err, doc){
                if(err) throw err;
                if(doc) {
                    return res.json({success: false, msg: 'Email Id already exists.'});
                    console.log("Found");
                } else {
                    return res.json({success: false, msg: 'Email Id doesnt exists.'});
                    console.log("Not found");
                }

            });   // this code throws cors error

 });

module.exports = router;
```

App.js

```
<div class="btn-group">                      
<button type="submit"> SUBSCRIBE </button> <br/>                            
</div>

onSubmit = (e) => {
    let msg='';
    console.log(this.state.email);
 e.preventDefault();

    const { email } = this.state;

    axios.post(`${config.host}/api/emails`, { email })  
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);

        alert('you have Subscribed');
      });

  }
```

I have also used below code in app.js to avoid this error,still it didn't work

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");   

  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});
```

How do I solve this? Thank you

Comment: Do you receive the data in your `Api-Email.js` ?

Comment: I don't receive any data. I get the error in Email.Js - "blocked by CORS Policy".